# Plotly: same axes, but autoscale?

Tags: python, plotly

For a scatterplot in Plotly, is it possible to keep the axes flexible, but that y and x always start at the same range?

I am plotting a graph where distances are very important. Therefore, when x and y are different scales, it can be very misleading. However, it is not possible to fix them ahead of time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both the `xaxis` and `yaxis` layout properties, have a property called `range`, in this we can provide the `max` and `min` values, below are the properties you need to play around with to achieve what you want!

> **nticks (integer greater than or equal to 0)** 
>  default: 0  
>  Specifies the maximum number of ticks for the particular axis. The
>   actual number of ticks will be chosen automatically to be less than or
>   equal to nticks. Has an effect only if tickmode is set to "auto".
>
> **tick0 (number or categorical coordinate string)**  
>  Sets the placement of the first tick on this axis. Use with dtick. If the axis
>   type is "log", then you must take the log of your starting tick (e.g.
>   to set the starting tick to 100, set the tick0 to 2) except when
>   dtick="L" (see dtick for more info). If the axis type is "date", it
>   should be a date string, like date data. If the axis type is
>   "category", it should be a number, using the scale where each category
>   is assigned a serial number from zero in the order it appears.
>
> **range (array)** 
>  Sets the range of this axis. If the axis `type` is "log", then you must take the log of your desired range (e.g. to
>   set the range from 1 to 100, set the range from 0 to 2). If the axis
>   `type` is "date", it should be date strings, like date data, though
>   Date objects and unix milliseconds will be accepted and converted to
>   strings. If the axis `type` is "category", it should be numbers, using
>   the scale where each category is assigned a serial number from zero in
>   the order it appears.  Each object has one or more of the keys listed
>   below.
>
> **dtick (number or categorical coordinate string)**
>   Sets the step
>   in-between ticks on this axis. Use with `tick0`. Must be a positive
>   number, or special strings available to "log" and "date" axes....

Check the [`official documentation`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/) also.

Here is a working example for reference.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  y: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
  type: 'scatter'
};
var trace2 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  y: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
var range = [1,8];
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    range: range
  },
  yaxis: {
    range: range   
  }
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
   <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  <script>
  /* JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE */
  </script>
</body>
```

If your issue is resolved completely, please let me know!!

Comment: But in your code sniplet it seems that the ranges are set but are different? That is not the goal. 

They should be flexible, but vary together.

Comment: @KimO Did this answer help you?

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I now they have a fixed range, don't they?

Comment: @KimO A graph will always have a fixed range, based on the data present, here I have set them to the fixed range since you require both to scale equally, there is no property that is going to ensure both 
 axis will have the same limits unless you set it manually using `range`

Comment: That is not really flexible then. 

Thank you for your answer though!